# get last value from select

Tags: sql, oracle

hi I'm trying to get the last value from a select, it that possible? I've tried the following:

```
update order set order_total =
(select last item_cost  * order_quantity
FROM order_stock, order
WHERE order_stock.menu_item = 
order.menu_item);
```

if i select  item_cost  * order_quantity
    FROM order_stock, order
    WHERE order_stock.menu_item = 
    order.menu_item it will return 2 values , i only want get retrieve the last entry

Comment: I do not see any `ORDER BY`. What do you mean by "*last*"?

Comment: Please provide minimal sample  data and expected result

Comment: if i select item_cost * order_quantity FROM order_stock, order WHERE order_stock.menu_item = order.menu_item it will return 2 values, 200 and 400. i need to select 400

Comment: Use max of then will get what u want

Comment: Side note: You should always use explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of old join syntax which uses commas

Comment: @OtoShavadze: There are different opinions.I don't think one should use always this ugly syntax.

Comment: @alex - How do you know its the value of 400 ? Is it ALWAYS the highest ? Is it possible to get -ve values ?

Comment: @miracle173 - I don't understand, which one syntax is ugly for you?  explicit JOIN or old comma style ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze For me the join syntax is ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick google, I found this:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

The page suggests multiple methods for different sql versions, since you tagged your question with oracle I will provide that one here:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <=1
ORDER BY column_name DESC;
```

Comment: LAST() isn't a function in Oracle.  In addition, the where clause is processed before order by clause.  Therefore, you are highly unlikely the get the value that you want from that query.

Comment: -1, From the linked site: "Note: The LAST() function is only supported in MS Access." But in Oracle there is a function named ["last"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions071.htm). The example is nonsense, though it is from the site you linked to. Oracle first applies the select clause and then sorts the result set. So the "order by" has no effect.

Comment: This may be what the OP is prepared to accept but the answer itself is wrong and misleading.